# Generics, ToArray etc

Tags: c#, java

We have a C# code base that we have to deploy on Java.

We are creating a migration engine that reads C# and writes Java.

We have created stub class for the classes from system that are used in our code, and are implementing them.

When I came to do `List<T>` in Java, I ran into problems while implementing `ToArray`.

For what I understand, because of the major deference between Java and C# in terms of generics, there is no way of knowing the type of the generic class, and thus no way of creating a typed array.

Is this final, or any of you know of some clever way of doing `ToArray` in a generic class without passing an array or a type as a parameter here or in the constructor.

Comment: do you mean this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation

Comment: Probably best off converting the arrays to `List`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should have a look at [Grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=130) and don't reinvent the wheel. It's a MSIL to Java bytecode compiler and it's a mature product.

Answer (score 6):

> We are creating a migration engine that reads c# and writes Java.

I hate to throw a monkey wrench into this plan, but this sounds like a truly wretched idea. You are going to wind up with an unidiomatic mess that will be difficult to maintain. It's the rough equivalent of running *War and Peace* through Google Translate and expecting to get a French version that means the exact same thing.

Comment: +1 - imagine the mess they'll have to generate if there's a `yield return` or `.Where` or `.Select`, etc.

Comment: We are looking only to migrate our own code, in a specific case. No messy yield etc...

We are very much aware of the readability issue, and aim on resolving it as well. 

We have done so very successfully in the past, and plan to do the same here.

Comment: @Noam: As long as you're aware of the limitations, then okie doke. I thought I should raise it nonetheless, just so that people didn't think this was a good idea in general.

Comment: We tried this at a previous job, generating php from python.  We ended up with bad php which we had to manually fix where the generator messed up.  For every python change, we had to keep running the generator and often manually merge the changes into the now manually modified php code.  It was bad.  You may be able to get this right, but you have to be super careful.

Answer (score 2):

Lists in java have two `toArray()` methods by contract.

- no-argument method, which returns `Object[]`
- a method accepting an argument of type `T[]`.

The latter looks like this in its `ArrayList` implementation (`elementData` is the array backing the list):

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size) {
        // Make a new array of a's runtime type, but my contents:
        return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
    }
    System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
    if (a.length > size) {
        a[size] = null;
    }
    return a;
}
```

The parameter which is passed is described in the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29) as follows:

> the array into which the elements of this list are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.

So in case you still want to implement a list yourself, follow this approach - i.e. create the array of the appropriate type beforehand and pass it to a generic method.

Answer (score 0):

You could look through the contents and find the most specific superclass of all elements. Of course, that could turn out to be more specific than the declared generic type, and what it should do with an empty list is an interesting question...

Comment: Interesting Idea, but will not work in those cases you specified.